# Findbugs on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, findbugs

I'm trying to configure Finbugs on Jenkins. 
My app versions:

- Jenkins:  1.624
- FindBugs-jsr305  com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
- FindBugs Plug-in 4.61
- Maven 2.2.1
- java 1.6.0_43

Locally I don't have any problems to prepare report using command:

```
mvn clean -D"dependency.locations.enabled=false" compile site
```

but unfortunately I've a problem on jenkins: My logs are :

```
  ERROR: Could not find local repository for 2.2.1
[FATAL ERROR] hudson.maven.agent.PluginManagerInterceptor$1MojoIntercepterImpl#configureComponent(...) caused a linkage error (java.lang.VerifyError) and may be out-of-date. Check the realms:
[FATAL ERROR] Plugin realm = app0.child-container[org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.3.2-fuse-00-00]
urls[0] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-codegen-plugin/2.3.2-fuse-00-00/cxf-codegen-plugin-2.3.2-fuse-00-00.jar
urls[1] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-artifact-resolver/1.0/maven-artifact-resolver-1.0.jar
urls[2] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
urls[3] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-tools-common/2.3.2-fuse-00-00/cxf-tools-common-2.3.2-fuse-00-00.jar
urls[4] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.6.4/velocity-1.6.4.jar
urls[5] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
urls[6] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.5/commons-lang-2.5.jar
urls[7] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
urls[8] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/wsdl4j/wsdl4j/1.6.2/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
urls[9] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-xjc/2.1.13/jaxb-xjc-2.1.13.jar
urls[10] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.1.13/jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar
urls[11] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-api/2.3.2-fuse-00-00/cxf-api-2.3.2-fuse-00-00.jar
urls[12] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-common-utilities/2.3.2-fuse-00-00/cxf-common-utilities-2.3.2-fuse-00-00.jar
urls[13] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema/1.4.7/XmlSchema-1.4.7.jar
urls[14] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/woodstox-core-asl/4.0.8/woodstox-core-asl-4.0.8.jar
urls[15] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.0.2/stax2-api-3.0.2.jar
urls[16] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/neethi/neethi/2.0.4/neethi-2.0.4.jar
urls[17] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
urls[18] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-common-schemas/2.3.2-fuse-00-00/cxf-common-schemas-2.3.2-fuse-00-00.jar
urls[19] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-core/2.3.2-fuse-00-00/cxf-rt-core-2.3.2-fuse-00-00.jar
urls[20] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec/1.7.1/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar
urls[21] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-tools-wsdlto-core/2.3.2-fuse-00-00/cxf-tools-wsdlto-core-2.3.2-fuse-00-00.jar
urls[22] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-tools-validator/2.3.2-fuse-00-00/cxf-tools-validator-2.3.2-fuse-00-00.jar
urls[23] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb/2.3.2-fuse-00-00/cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb-2.3.2-fuse-00-00.jar
urls[24] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws/2.3.2-fuse-00-00/cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws-2.3.2-fuse-00-00.jar
urls[25] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/xml-resolver/xml-resolver/1.2/xml-resolver-1.2.jar
urls[26] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/springframework/spring-core/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
urls[27] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/springframework/spring-asm/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
urls[28] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
urls[29] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/springframework/spring-context/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
urls[30] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
urls[31] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
urls[32] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
urls[33] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.1/ant-1.8.1.jar
urls[34] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.8.1/ant-launcher-1.8.1.jar
urls[35] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/ant/ant-nodeps/1.8.1/ant-nodeps-1.8.1.jar
[FATAL ERROR] Container realm = plexus.core.maven
urls[0] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-webdav-jackrabbit/1.0-beta-6/wagon-webdav-jackrabbit-1.0-beta-6.jar
urls[1] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-http-shared/1.0-beta-6/wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-6.jar
urls[2] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/nekohtml/xercesMinimal/1.9.6.2/xercesMinimal-1.9.6.2.jar
urls[3] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/nekohtml/nekohtml/1.9.6.2/nekohtml-1.9.6.2.jar
urls[4] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
urls[5] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.4/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
urls[6] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.jar
urls[7] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
urls[8] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-webdav/1.5.0/jackrabbit-webdav-1.5.0.jar
urls[9] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/apache/jackrabbit/jackrabbit-jcr-commons/1.5.0/jackrabbit-jcr-commons-1.5.0.jar
urls[10] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.3/slf4j-api-1.5.3.jar
urls[11] = file:/var/fuse-base/apache-servicemix-4.3.1-devDD/project-repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.5.3/slf4j-nop-1.5.3.jar
ERROR: Could not find local repository for 2.2.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64OutputStream.<init>(Ljava/io/OutputStream;Z)V @11: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/commons/codec/binary/BaseNCodec'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @11
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis, 'java/io/OutputStream', integer }
    stack: { uninitializedThis, 'java/io/OutputStream', 'org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64', integer }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2b bb00 0259 03b7 0003 1cb7 0004 b1  

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64OutputStream.<init>(Ljava/io/OutputStream;Z)V @11: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Type 'org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/commons/codec/binary/BaseNCodec'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @11
    flags: { flagThisUninit }
    locals: { uninitializedThis, 'java/io/OutputStream', integer }
    stack: { uninitializedThis, 'java/io/OutputStream', 'org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64', integer }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a2b bb00 0259 03b7 0003 1cb7 0004 b1  

    at hudson.console.ConsoleNote.encodeToBytes(ConsoleNote.java:182)
    at hudson.console.ConsoleNote.encodeTo(ConsoleNote.java:157)
    at hudson.util.StreamTaskListener.annotate(StreamTaskListener.java:159)
    at hudson.util.StreamTaskListener._error(StreamTaskListener.java:134)
    at hudson.util.StreamTaskListener.error(StreamTaskListener.java:143)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter.recordParents(MavenFingerprinter.java:144)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenFingerprinter.postBuild(MavenFingerprinter.java:110)
    at hudson.maven.Maven2Builder.postModule(Maven2Builder.java:129)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuilder$Adapter.fireLeaveModule(MavenBuilder.java:353)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuilder$Adapter.postBuild(MavenBuilder.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.execute(LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at hudson.maven.agent.Main.launch(Main.java:205)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuilder.call(MavenBuilder.java:154)
    at hudson.maven.Maven2Builder.call(Maven2Builder.java:79)
    at hudson.maven.Maven2Builder.call(Maven2Builder.java:55)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

my pom.xml:

```
  ...
        <findbugs.version>2.5.3</findbugs.version>
    ...
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <linkXref>true</linkXref>
                                <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
                                <minimumTokens>30</minimumTokens>
                                <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                           <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>${findbugs.version}</version>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
          <reporting>
             <plugins>
                <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>${surefire.reportplugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                   <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>${findbugs.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
              </plugins>
           </reporting>
```

UPDATE:
I've mvn plugin in version : 2.11
and that's my configuration:
[image: Image with Jenkins Configuration]

and my external mvn, which inside /usr/local/maven has configuration with:

```
<localRepository>my_local_repo</localRepository>

<proxies>
        <proxy>
                <id>optional</id>
                <active>true</active>
                <protocol>http</protocol>
                <host>my.host</host>
                <port>3128</port>
                <nonProxyHosts>custom.com.pl</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

Comment: First question: Why are you using Maven 2.2.1 ? Furthermore which looks strange: `ERROR: Could not find local repository for 2.2.1`? Furthermore why using `cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5.2` and not

Comment: @khamarbaise - I've to use this version of maven, cause it's quite huge and old project and I need to compile it through maven 2. Yes I also don't understand this error about local repository for 2.2.1. Could it be connected with proxy? Maybe proxy on jenkins? What do you mean about cobertura? I wanted to use it.

Comment: If you behind a proxy yes please check it...Ah...cobertura was also an old version... [Maven 2 is EoL](http://maven.apache.org/maven-2.x-eol.html) ...

Comment: I've edited it, but still got a problem only on Jenkins

Comment: In case you have to cope with a proxy, is your maven client configured accordingly?

Comment: I've updated. the question. I don't wknow what is wrong in this configuration. Yes, my mvn is configured and yes, I'm using proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the maven project configuration to either:

- Local to the executor
- Local to the work space

[image: Manage Jenkins]

You can also try a workaround for this:

- Instead of providing a local maven installation manually. Use install
  automatically in Maven installation and Jenkins will take care of all
  this issues.

Comment: I mean that it was connected with wrong maven configuration project. I've changed it - I will put my answer.

Comment: Please don't hesitate to mark the question as answered, if the above has helped :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on maven 3.2.3, I found that jenkins wanted the jenkins.localRepository to be set, I don't know your exact setup, but I believe that it needs to be pointed at the M2 somehow. I have seen the following used

```
-Dmaven.repo.local="$path_to_m2"
```

but in your case it may be:

```
-Djenkins.localRepository="$path_to_m2"
```

Comment: I've updated. the question. I don't wknow what is wrong in this configuration.

Comment: Can you confirm when you have logged into the build slave that the ~/.m2/repository exists? As well as the one that is specified in the path. Maybe if the maven plugin is having trouble or passing in mystery params etc, it might be worth having a crack at it manually from a `shell script` rather than a `maven build`.

Comment: Yes, because home directory for jenkins is his job and that's true. I've directory: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/my-job/workspace where is my local repository and what's more mvn clean -D"dependency.locations.enabled=false" compile site works there when I invoke it locally in console.

Comment: Seems to be a bug registered along the same lines. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18441 but should have been resolved before your version of jenkins.
In looking at the job configuration, there is a specific location that is available for the m2 to be provided and seems to default to ~/.m2/repository, could you modify the location to be within the workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've decided to use execute shell with commands:

```
cd $WORKSPACE
rm -rf target
mvn clean -D"dependency.locations.enabled=false" compile site -e -X
```

now my stack is, but it looks as an issue with jenkins user permissions, so I think I can deal with that.

```
[DEBUG] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to generate types.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.forkProjectLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1205)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.forkLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1033)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:663)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to generate types.
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.WSDL2JavaMojo.callWsdl2Java(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:413)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Failed to generate types.
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.generate(JAXBDataBinding.java:745)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:586)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:237)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:137)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:280)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.WSDL2JavaMojo.callWsdl2Java(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:410)
    ... 24 more
```

I've also changed maven plugin to use:

```
maven opts: -Dmaven.repo.local=my-repo-directory
```

I've checked to use private maven repository with strategy: Local to the executor